# Discrepancy When Calculating Variance

Tags: probability

I have the following problem, asking what is the variance of the number of successes when $n$ independent Bernoulli trials are performed, where, on each trial, $p$ is the probability of success and $q$ is the probability of failure?

For a discrete random variable $X(X_1,\ldots, X_n)$ where $X_i=1$ if the trial is a success and $X_i=0$ if the trial is a failure, it is clear that $E(X_i)=p$, $E(X)=np$, and $V(X_i)=pq$.  But I seem to be able to find two different values for $V(X)$ based on my approach and can't reconcile the difference.  Given that $V(X)=E(X^2)-E(X)^2$, I have $E(X^2)=np$ and $E(X)^2=(np)^2$ so $V(X)=np-(np)^2=np(1-np)$.  But I also know that $V(X)=V(X_1)+\cdots+V(X_n)$ and solving for $V(X)$ using this relationship yields $V(X)=npq$.

There must be some silly mistake that I'm missing, but I can't seem to find it.  Could someone please point out the difference in these two approaches?

Comment: $E(X^2)$ is not $np = E(X)$ (except for $n=1$ or $p=0$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X= \sum X_i$ then $X^2 = \left(\sum X_i  \right)^2,$ not $\sum \left(X_i^2  \right)$.

So $E[X^2] = E\left[\left(\sum X_i  \right)^2\right] = E\left[\displaystyle\sum_i \left(X_i^2  \right)\right] +  E\left[\displaystyle\sum_{i,j:i\not = j} \left(X_i X_j  \right)\right] = np + n(n-1)p^2$.

If you use this then $V[X] = E[X^2] - (E[X])^2 = np + n(n-1)p^2 - n^2p^2 = np-np^2$ which is $np(1-p)=npq$, the same as your other derivation.

Comment: This is what I needed.  Could you explain your work on the second line?  It's not clear to me how you moved from the second to leftmost to the second to rightmost to the rightmost equation.  If it's easier, you could just point me to a reference instead.

Comment: @user93189: For example: $(X_1+X_2+X_3)^2$ $ = (X_1^2+X_2^2+X_3^2)+(X_1X_2+X_1X_3+X_2X_1+X_2X_3+X_3X_1+X_3X_2)$ and then take the expectations of both sides

Answer (score 2):

How you concluded that $E(X^2)=np$ you don't tell us, but it is incorrect.

For example, supposing $n=2$ and $p=1/2$, we have
$$
X^2=\begin{cases} 0 & \text{with probability }1/4, \\
1 & \text{with probability }1/2, \\
4 & \text{with probability }1/4. \end{cases}
$$
So
$$
E(X^2) = \frac32 \ne 1 = np.
$$